# How do i map one shortcut key to a sequence of tags (tasks) in lighttable?

Tags: lighttable

Say, for example, I want to bind a key "`ctrl+d`" to duplicate current line in LightTable. For that, to emulate duplication of the current line, I want to run a series of actions like `[:editor.select-line :editor.copy :editor.selection.clear :editor.new-line-indent :editor.line-start :editor.paste]`

How do I achieve this?

Note: I am aware of the `:editor.sublime.duplicateLine` tag which duplicates the line, but this is just the example. In general, I want to map a shortcut to a sequence of tags/tasks.

http://lighttable.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to bind the key? You seem to have most of it set. Just open up user.keymap (ctrl-space "user keymap") and add this:

```
[:editor "ctrl+d" :editor.select-line
                  :editor.copy
                  :editor.selection.clear
                  :editor.new-line-indent
                  :editor.line-start
                  :editor.paste]
```

There is no requirement that you put it on separate lines like that of course.

Or are you asking for something more complicated?

Comment: I did not know that I could just put them in sequence and it would execute those in sequence. I actually tried to keep them in a vector and it did not work. Thank you.